# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'make'

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## Issue

`catkin build` fails on `ros:noetic-ros-base`.

```
$ docker pull ros:noetic-ros-base
noetic-ros-base: Pulling from library/ros
Digest: sha256:66ba20ba51d44779dff11f490b0f30ab04f8ca15935f32ea5f058f1ac011d84d
:
root@07979acfa2c3:/cws# history
 1  DIR=/cws && mkdir -p $DIR/src && apt update && apt install -y python3-catkin-tools
 7  cd $DIR && catkin init && catkin config --install
 9  source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash       
# catkin build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/catkin", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('catkin-tools==0.7.1', 'console_scripts', 'catkin')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 266, in main
    catkin_main(sysargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 261, in catkin_main
    sys.exit(args.main(args) or 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/cli.py", line 273, in main
    make_args, makeflags, cli_flags, jobserver = configure_make_args(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/argument_parsing.py", line 359, in configure_make_args
    job_server.initialize(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/execution/job_server.py", line 305, in initialize
    JobServer._gnu_make = GnuMake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/execution/job_server.py", line 115, in __init__
    if test_gnu_make_support():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/execution/job_server.py", line 110, in test_gnu_make_support
    return test_gnu_make_support_common(JOBSERVER_SUPPORT_MAKEFILE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_tools/execution/job_server.py", line 83, in test_gnu_make_support_common
    ret = subprocess.call(['make', '-f', makefile, '-j2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'make'
```

`catkin_make` also fails, but a different error, which looks similar to what's reported in https://answers.ros.org/question/384705

```
root@609b91fd3266:/cws# rm -fr .catkin_tools/                     
root@609b91fd3266:/cws# catkin_make                                                                                                                            
Base path: /cws                                        
Source space: /cws/src                                            
Build space: /cws/build                                   
Devel space: /cws/devel                                
Install space: /cws/install                               
Creating symlink "/cws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####                                                                                                                                                           
#### Running command: "cmake /cws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/cws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/cws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/cws/build"
####                                                              
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!               
See also "/cws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".   
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384795/filenotfounderror:-%5Berrno-2%5D-no-such-file-or-directory:-%27make%27/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like similar / the same background as https://answers.ros.org/question/384705.

In my case, the issue went away after either:

- switching the Docker image  to `ros:noetic-ros-core`.
- installing `build-essential`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2021-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0